# Why Include Header and Payload in JWT Token?

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, access-token

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple here, but I just started learning about JWT tokens for authenticating and, as I understand it, the structure of a JWT token is:

```
Base64UrlEncode(Header) + '.' +  Base64UrlEncode(Payload) + '.' + CreateSignature(Header, Payload, Secret_Key)
```

And what I'm understanding is that you send this to the client and it allows the client to send this back to the server when needed. At which point you decrypt the Signature to make sure it wasn't tampered with using your private key.

The part I'm confused about is why you need the first part of `Base64UrlEncode(Header) + '.' +  Base64UrlEncode(Payload) + '.'` which is easily converted back to plain-text, then?

Since you will be decrypting it on the server, couldn't you just pass the signature, decrypt it using your secret key and read the payload whereas no one else could?

It seems like this would be safer since the first part can be easily converted back to plain-text and give an attacker information such as `token expiration`, `userId` and the like that is stored in the payload.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature does not contain the payload. The signature can be as simple as a message authentication code (HMAC) of the hash (SHA256) of the jwt. So if you only sent the signature, that would work as a plain old session id, and the server would still have to store state, negating any benefit of a jwt.

You are right though, a jwt by default is not encrypted. While encoded with base64, from a security perspective it's just plain text and should not contain sensitive (secret) information. The only protection the signature provides is that when the server receives it back, it can make sure by checking the signature that the information in the jwt was not altered on the client.

The token not being encrypted allows the client to inspect its contents and figure out for example the expiry time, when it will have to obtain a new token, or the logged in user's id. The user who has the jwt would have this kind of information anyway, and others are not supposed to have the jwt, because they could use it for authentication to impersonate the user.

However, under special circumstances, you may still want to include sensitive info (ie. secrets) that you want to receive back on the server but don't want to disclose to the client. For that you can use an encrypted jwt (jwe). The drawback is that this token will be opaque for the client and you will probably have to implement application endpoints to retrieve all necessary information.

Comment: Thank you, Gabor. The part I'm still confused by is I get that having the unencrypted data allows the client to have some information, but the part that seems more scary to me is that this will be stored by the client and if a hacker were to receive even an expired token, they would have information such as userid or username possibly.
I just don't get why you would even bother including this back as part of a security token rather than just having a fully encrypted token that gets passed back and forth (I guess that being JWE as you mentioned). I just don't get the benefit.

Comment: Like I said, I just don't get why it would be part of the convention of the JWT to have this rather than JUST the encrypted last part and make the first 2 parts, at least, a choice rather than a convention.
But, truly, thank you so much for the clarification!!!

Comment: Single page javascript applications typically benefit from having the plaintext data, because they can spare a roundtrip to the server to get for example token lifetime or the userid. If this is not used, you can actually go for an encrypted jwt, which is not just the last part, because the last part is just a likely fixed length message authentication code (or a signature, depending on the algorithm chosen). As opposed to that, in an encrypted jwt the whole jwt (the actual data) is encrypted.

Comment: So yes, you're right, if the client doesn't need any data from the jwt (not the typical case), then an encrypted jwt might be more secure. However, against what? The typical data included in a jwt is not really sensitive, sharing a userid for instance with the actual user is ok in most applications. And on the other hand, encryption costs resources - quite a bit in fact. Also this will always be sent over https - an attacker has no easy way to gain access to even an expired jwt, so that limits the risk.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. It just seemed counter-intuitive, I guess, but I do get that a hacker getting the JWT is a bad thing regardless :)
Thank you so much for your time and explanation through this!